# (PHP) Checking items in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

Array(a,b,c,a,b)

Now, if I would like to check how many instances of "b" I can find in the array, how would I proceed?

Answer (score 5):

See the documentation for [array_count_values()](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). It seems to be what you are looking for.

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b');
$counts = array_count_values($array);
printf("Number of 'b's: %d\n", $counts['b']);
var_dump($counts);
```

Output:

> Number of 'b's: 2
>
> array(3) {
> ["a"]=> int(2)
> ["b"]=> int(2)
> ["c"]=> int(1)
> }

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_count_values($arr)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). This returns an associative array with each value in `$arr` as a key and that value's frequency in `$arr` as the value. Example:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 2);
$counts = array_count_values($arr);
$count_of_2 = $counts[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of instances by using this function..

```
 $b = array(a,b,c,a,b);

 function count_repeat($subj, $array) {
    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
       if($array[$i] == $subj) {
           $same[] = $array[$i]; //what this line does is put the same characters in the $same[] array.
        }
    return count($same);
 }

echo count_repeat('b', $b); // will return the value 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some fancy ways, a programmer should be able to solve this problem using **very basic programming operators**.
It is absolutely necessary to know how to use loops and conditions.

```
$count = 0;
$letters= array("a","b","c","a","b"); 
foreach ($letters as $char){
  if ($char == "b") $count = $count+1;
}
echo $count.' "b" found';
```

NOT a rocket science.